# Decode a 2D circle colour barcode

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv, coding in c++. I have a task given to me to decode a 2D circle barcode using an encoded array. I am up to the point where I am able to centralize the figure and get the line using Hough transforms.

Need help with how to read the colour in the images, note that each of the two adjacent blocks correspond to a letter.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this helps or not, but those colors are all `1` or `0` in either the R,G,B channels.  On or off.  (0 or 255 in byte formats).  If you think of them as bits, then there are 8 combinations of colors.  From Black (0,0,0) to White (1,1,1).  If two adjacent colors form a letter, then there are  64 different letters (2^6)

Comment: you are right, there are 64 characters, and if I combine all of them, it spits out a paragraph. The only thing is that the middle horizontal and vertical blocks are not to be read, they are only used to make the image upright.

Comment: Can you explain this : *note that each of the two adjacent blocks correspond to a letter* ?

Comment: I'd start by going in the middle, find a mono-colored block in order to know the offsets of each block and then go like for each offset + block length, check if homogeneous and bordered by a black frame, if yes, add to some vector.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load the image.  I suspect this isn't a problem because you are already using Hough transforms on it, but:

```
Mat img = imread(filename)
```

Once the image is loaded, you can grab any of the pixels using:

```
Scalar intensity = img.at<uchar>(y, x);
```

However, what you need to do is threshold the image. As I mentioned in the comments, the image colors are either `0` or `255` for each `RGB` channel.  This is on purpose for encoding the data in case there are image artifacts.  If the channel is above a certain color value, then you will consider that it's 'on' and if below, it's 'off'.

Threshold the image using [adaptiveThreshold](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html).  I would threshold down to binary 1 or 0.  This will produce RGB triplets that are one of eight (2^3) possible combinations, from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1).

Then you need to walk the pixels.  This is where it gets interesting.

You say each adjacent 2 pixels form a single letter. That's 2^6 or 64 different letters.  The next question is: are the letters arranged in scan lines, left-to-right, top to bottom? If yes, then it will be important to orientate the image using the crosshair in the center.

If the image is encoded radially (using polar coordinates) then things get a little trickier.  You need to use [cvLinearPolar](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#linearpolar) to [remap](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html) the image.

Otherwise you need to walk the whole image, stepping the size of the RGB blocks and discard any pixels whose distance from the center is greater than the radius of the circle. After reading all of the pixels into an array, group them by pairs.

---

At some point, I would say that using OpenCV to do this is heading towards machine learning.  There has to be some point where you can cut in and use Neural Networks to decode the image for you.  Once you have the circle (cutoff radius) and the image centered, you can convert to polar coordinates and discard everything outside the circle by cutting off everything greater than the radius of the circle.  Remember, polar coordinates are (r,theta), so you should be able to cutoff the right part of the polar image.

Then you could train a [Neural Network](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html) to take the polar image as input and spit out the paragraph.

You would have to provide lots of training data, and the trained model would still be reliant on your ability to pre-process the image.  This will include any affine transforms in case the image is tilted or rotated.  At that point you would say to yourself that you've done all the heavy lifting and the last little bit really isn't that hard.

However, once you get a process working for a clean image, you can start adding to steps to introduce ML to work on dirty images.  HoughCircles can be used to detect the part of an image to run detection on.  Next, you need to decide if the image inside the circle is a barcode or not.

A good barcode system will have parity bits or some other form of error correction, but you can use machine learning to cleanup output.

My 2 cents anyways.